# association.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript

For a project I have to evolve a piece of code but I can not. This bit of code initially allows me to toggle the 4 clickable elements of a certain form and it works perfectly.

```
const choices = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');

const toggleActiveClass = (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
};

const toggleActiveOnClick = (choice) => {
  choice.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass);
};

choices.forEach(toggleActiveOnClick);
```

However, now I have to make sure that when I select one or the other of the first 2 elements I can not toggle the other and the same for the next 2. I tried this piece of code but when I open the console in chrome tool i get the error message present in the title of this post. Here is the piece of code in question:

```
const upsell = document.querySelector('#test1 > .clickable');
const crossell = document.querySelector('#test2 > .clickable');
const standard = document.querySelector('#test3 > .clickable');
const discount = document.querySelector('#test4 > .clickable');

const choices = [ upsell, crossell, standard, discount ];

const toggleActiveClass = (event) => {
  if (event === upsell) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    crossell.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (event === crossell) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    upsell.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (event === standard) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    discount.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (event === discount) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    standard.classList.remove('active');
  }
};

const toggleActiveOnClick = (choice) => {
  choice.addEventListener('click', toggleActiveClass);
};


choices.forEach(toggleActiveOnClick);
```

Here is the corresponding html

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="bundle-type">Bundle Type</label>
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center pt-4">
            <div id="test1">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                <small>Upsell</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test2">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                <small>Cros-sell</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <label for="bundle-type">Offer Type</label>
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center pt-4">
            <div id="test3">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-gift"></i>
                <small>Standard</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test4">
              <div class="clickable">
                <i class="fas fa-percent"></i>
                <small>Discounted</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.clickable i {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clickable:hover i {
  color: #167FFB;
}

.clickable.active {
  color: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
}

.clickable.active i {
  color: #0F60C4;
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns `null` if it can't find a DOM node. Meaning that your error is almost certainly coming from `event.currentTarget.classList`: one of your events doesn't have a `.currentTarget` property. Or not: you haven't really posted enough for us to say. Please post the **exact** error message and preferably let us know which line of code it points to (we don't have your line numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Change all `event ===` to `event.currentTarget ===` as that is where the element reference is held.